# equalTo datasnapshot from Firebase Realtime database returning null value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-toast

When the user starts the activity, a Toast should pop up containing parent node where the value "drinkManufacturerID" is equal to a given String. However, a null value is being returned in the Toast.

Relevant code:

```
public class DealRawDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference databaseDrinks;

String keys;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_deal_raw_data);

    databaseDrinks = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("drinks").child("-LWLuM2nesg0uaP0dLSn");

    databaseDrinks.orderByChild("drinkManufacturerID").equalTo("D1eY5v9guwSIWMvfLoq8xGywrT53").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                keys = datas.getKey();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

   Toast.makeText(this, keys, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Firebase Realtime Database Structure:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to display a Toast message containg the value of your `keys` variable outside the callback, you'll always get `null` since the `onDataChange()` has an asynchronous behavior. Because that method returns immediately, the value of your `keys` variable you're trying to display, has not been populated from the callback yet. There are no guarantees about how long it will take. So it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that data is available.

A quick solve for this problem would be to use move the following line of code:

```
Toast.makeText(this, keys, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Right after the for loops ends, otherwise I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.

**Edit:** Please see below the entire code:

```
public class DealRawDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference databaseDrinks;
    String keys;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_deal_raw_data);
        databaseDrinks = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("drinks").child("-LWLuM2nesg0uaP0dLSn");
        databaseDrinks.orderByChild("drinkManufacturerID").equalTo("D1eY5v9guwSIWMvfLoq8xGywrT53").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    keys = datas.getKey();
                }
                Toast.makeText(this, keys, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //Should work!!
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: where should I move the toast exactly to for it to work?

Comment: Ah yes it does, I found my issue. I had to replace "this" with "getApplicationContext()". Thanks.